# Showing top 5 post in django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

in my project i want to show top 5 post in home section by categories.i fetch all post in home sections and if category is same i showed the post.but forloop.counter is not suitable in this situation.i need counter to break the loop or if condition.but i cant. please help me.

> views.py

```
def home(request):
 category = Category.objects.all().filter(parent=None)
 post_by_category = Post.objects.filter(published=True).order_by('-category')
 slider = Post.objects.filter(slider=True).order_by('-created_on')


 context = {
      'category':category,
      'post_by_category':post_by_category,
      'slider':slider,
 }


 return render(request,'home.html',context)
```

> home.html

```
<div class="col-md-9">

      {% for post in post_by_category %}

      {% if post.category.category_name  == category.category_name %}

      <div class="d-lg-flex post-entry-2">
        <a href="{{post.get_url}}" class="me-4 thumbnail mb-4 mb-lg-0 d-inline-block">
          <img src="{{post.heder_image.url}}" alt="" class="img-fluid">
        </a>
        <div>
          <div class="post-meta"><span class="date"><a href="{{category.get_url }}">{{category.category_name }}</a>
            </span> <span class="mx-1">&bullet;</span> <span>Jul
              5th '22</span></div>
          <h3><a href="{{post.get_url}}">{{post.title}}</a></h3>
          <p>{{post.meta_description}}</p>
          <div class="d-flex align-items-center author">
            <div class="photo"><img style="width:50px;height:50px;border-radius:50%"
                src="{{user.profile.profile_picture.url}}" alt="" class="img-fluid"></div>
            <div class="name">
              <h3 class="m-0 p-0">{{post.author.first_name}} {{post.author.last_name}}</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      {% endif %}

      {% endfor %}

    </div>
```

Comment: In your **home** view you can use a function to loop over categories of posts and then only fetch 5 for each using the slice operator [:5].

Comment: can you write the function please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add slice after filter so for example:

```
 post_by_category = Post.objects.filter(published=True).order_by('-category')[:5]
```

About inserting them into dictionary. 
If you only got some categories, you could filter them each and slice 5 of them and insert it to your dictionary

```
news = Post.objects.filter(category="news")[:5]
travel = Post.objects.filter(category="travel")[:5]

categories = {
    'news': news,
    'travel': travel
}
```

Or you could filter all your posts, and then loop them and check their categories and insert them to respective lists (This code is highly inefficient btw, as you could stop after adding 5 data on all lists)

```
news_post_list = list()
travel_post_list = list()

for post in posts:
    if post.category == "news":
        news_post_list.append(post)
    elif post.category == "travel":
        travel_post_list.append(post)

categories = {
    'news': news_post_list[:5],
    'travel': travel_post_list[:5]
}
```

You got the idea

Comment: it will show only recently categories top 5 post..but in home.html i compare category

Comment: What about you split your posts by categories (max 5 each), add them to dictionary, then display them at your template ?

Comment: how can i split and add it in dictionary.

Comment: I edit the answer. Hopefully it helps although its inefficient

Comment: i have  to code 5 times if i have 5 category..

Comment: You could get all your categories using `values_list` and insert them as key with empty list value in dictionary